# IPython plots show up in IDLE

Tags: python, ipython

This is quite embarrassing, but every time i use `plot()` with IPython it pop's up in the IDLE window opposed to showning it inline. How can I change this?

Comment: How's that embarrassing? More precisely, where does it say the figures should show up inline? Note: I've never used IDLE, but my IPython use always pops up a separate figure window. Only exception: when using the `--notebook` option with my webbrowser.

Comment: i somehow missed to specify the inline argument...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start ipython with

```
$ ipython --pylab=inline
```

or 
in ipython

```
In[x]: %pylab inline
```

Comment: thanks, i for some reason thought that using --pylab only would do the trick, and didn't specify inline.